# Download file code not working for firefox and IE

Tags: asp.net, download

I have created a code for downloading images. It works fine if the file name has no special characters or the punctuation marks. But I found an issue when the file name contains other language's character or ',' in the file name.

My code is :

```
private void AddFile(SPFile file)
{
    try
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file.Name);
        string filename = GeneralMethods.MakeValidFileName(file.Name);
        filename += fileInfo.Extension;
        byte[] obj = (byte[])file.OpenBinary();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= " + filename);
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        if (Response.IsClientConnected)
            Response.BinaryWrite(obj);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {           
    }
    finally
    {

    }
}
```

To avoid the other language's characters and other punctuation marks in the file name I created one method to replace non English character to blank.

```
    public static string MakeValidFileName(string name)
    {
        Regex rgx = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]");
        return rgx.Replace(name, "");
    }
```

In my scenario, I have two files 'xäbace 11,5 hm' & 'Png file'. I am able to download these files in Chrome but not able to download in IE & Firefox. And one more thing, the file is downloaded in Firefox but without extension. i.e. the file gets downloaded and after completing if I add extension to that file it works fine.

What should I do to tackle the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sincerely, I don't understand ASP.
But it seems you are permitting spaces in file names. You should avoid it, because some browsers will force URL encode of the filename, replacing spaces by %20 and messing up with the file path.
Also, in some languages (PHP) spaces in file names can in some cases, force the MIME type to text/html.

For many reasons you should the, avoid spaces in files to be downloaded or just used in the web.